# Can't Add Nameservers 16.04 LTS virtual install

Tags: networking, 16.04, dns

Just did a fresh install of 16.04 LTS in virtual mode on Hyper-V... having trouble getting DNS resolution...

Finally got network working by using ifconfig add eth0 10.0.0.1/24, added default gateway with route add... but can't seem to figure out how to add nameservers... Then I completely screwed up networking by deleting all routes (experimenting). Couldn't get networking to work at all. Finally got network up again by adding all config to /etc/network/interfaces for auto eth0:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 10.0.0.1
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 10.0.0.200
dns-nameservers 10.0.0.50 10.0.0.51
```

Restarted the system after adding in config and now I can ping other hosts on network, but still no DNS resolution... What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ nmcli connection modify eth0 ipv4.dns 10.0.0.50
# systemctl restart NetworkManager.service
```

- Editing **/etc/resolv.conf** is not an option because *resolv.conf* will be overridden with networkmanager.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting.. you could also try defining nameserver in */etc/resolv.conf*
which should look something like this:

```
nameserver 10.0.0.50 10.0.0.51
```